# C++11 compatibility

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible yet to have a package in ROS compiled with c++ 11 support? Or does ROS need to be compiled from source with c++ 11? If so, is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67784/c++11-compatibility/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2013-07-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I might be wrong but would like to give it a try.

Given that [ROS supports only C++03 up to Hydro so far](http://answers.ros.org/question/12227/ros-and-c11/) and as far as I haven't seen discussion about `C++0x` support, I think your question falls into general `C++` discussion. And [because of possible API incompatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494101/any-issues-with-mixing-libraries-with-and-without-std-c0x), mixing compiled `C++03` and `C++0x` may or may not work.

---

UPDATE) [This newer thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/77941/c11-with-ros-on-osx/?comment=78506#comment-78506) might answer more to your interest.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-07-20**:
I had seen that post too, but since it was from 2011 I had hoped it would be possible by now. I added the c++0x flag and the c++11 flag but in both cases I get an error from some ros messages. Guessing it is not possible yet, but it has been out for a while now so making that step seems logical.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-22**:
I would suggest then to start discussion in [ros-users](https://code.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/ros-users) (I'm not sure which component is the right place).

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-09-13**:
Thank you for the update, I am indeed using OSX. Too bad c++11 support doesn't work proper on OSX then.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nowadays it is possible.

Just add this to your CMakeLists.txt file

> if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
> add_definitions(-std=gnu++0x)
> endif()

Be careful with the boost::shared_ptr pointers that are intensively used in ROS and but they are not compatible with std::shared_ptr

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1